# Unable to run jmeter test file using Java code in my maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, jmeter

I am running a .jmx file using JMeter java code in my maven project. I have recorded a .jmx file using blazemeter. Please refer to the below code that I have tried.

```
package com.solitera.automation.controller;

import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class JMeterFromExistingJMX {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        // JMeter Engine
        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();


        // Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc.
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("D:/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin/jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("D:/apache-jmeter-5.1.1");
        JMeterUtils.initLogging();// you can comment this line out to see extra log messages of i.e. DEBUG level
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();

        // Initialize JMeter SaveService
        SaveService.loadProperties();

        // Load existing .jmx Test Plan
       /* FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("D:/Ecllipse_project_workspace2/slt_automation/src/test/jmeter/slt_autoMa_Test.jmx");
        HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(in);
        in.close();*/

        HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(new File("D:/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/extras/slt_autoMa_Test.jmx"));

        // Run JMeter Test
        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        jmeter.run();
    }


}
```

**After run as a Java Application in eclipse -> Output is :**

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found
>   binding in
>   [jar:file:/C:/Users/rajan/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/C:/Users/rajan/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.12.1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.12.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
>   explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
>   [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder] 18:56:16.586
>   [main] WARN org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils - Exception 'null'
>   occurred when fetching boolean property:'server.exitaftertest',
>   defaulting to: false 18:56:16.594 [main] WARN
>   org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils - Exception 'null' occurred when
>   fetching boolean property:'jmeterengine.remote.system.exit',
>   defaulting to: false 18:56:16.594 [main] WARN
>   org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils - Exception 'null' occurred when
>   fetching boolean property:'jmeterengine.stopfail.system.exit',
>   defaulting to: true 18:56:16.594 [main] WARN
>   org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils - Exception 'null' occurred when
>   fetching boolean property:'jmeterengine.force.system.exit', defaulting
>   to: false 18:56:16.610 [main] INFO org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils
>   - Setting Locale to en_IN 18:56:17.109 [main] INFO org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService - Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2.
>   Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2 18:56:17.148 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService - Using SaveService properties file
>   encoding UTF-8 18:56:17.156 [main] WARN
>   org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService - Can't register a converter:
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPResultConverter
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPResultConverter  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
>   org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.registerConverter(SaveService.java:285)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.registerConverter(SaveService.java:260)
>     at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.initProps(SaveService.java:246)
>     at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.(SaveService.java:165)
>     at
>   com.solitera.automation.controller.JMeterFromExistingJMX.main(JMeterFromExistingJMX.java:75)
>   18:56:17.157 [main] INFO org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService - Using
>   SaveService properties version 5.0 18:56:17.175 [main] WARN
>   org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService - Can't register a converter:
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBaseConverter
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBaseConverter  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
>   org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.registerConverter(SaveService.java:285)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.registerConverter(SaveService.java:260)
>     at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.initProps(SaveService.java:246)
>     at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.(SaveService.java:165)
>     at
>   com.solitera.automation.controller.JMeterFromExistingJMX.main(JMeterFromExistingJMX.java:75)
>   18:56:17.181 [main] INFO org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService - Loading
>   file: D:\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\extras\slt_autoMa_Test.jmx Exception in
>   thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML
>   from:'D:\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\extras\slt_autoMa_Test.jmx'.  Cause:
>   CannotResolveClassException:
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HeaderManager
>
> Detail:com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
>   ---- Debugging information ---- cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException cause-message 
>   :  first-jmeter-class  :
>   org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
>   class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
>   required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
>   converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
>   path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/HeaderManager
>   line number         : 14 version             : 5.2.1
>   -------------------------------   at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:459)    at
>   org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.loadTree(SaveService.java:432)     at
>   com.solitera.automation.controller.JMeterFromExistingJMX.main(JMeterFromExistingJMX.java:82)
>   Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
>   ---- Debugging information ---- cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException cause-message 
>   :  first-jmeter-class  :
>   org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
>   class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
>   required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
>   converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
>   path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/HeaderManager
>   line number         : 14 version             : 5.2.1
>   -------------------------------   at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.createConversionException(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.unmarshal(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:96)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
>     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1487)    at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1467)     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1338)   at
>   org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:449)     ...
>   2 more Caused by:
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
>   ---- Debugging information ---- cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
>   cause-message       :
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HeaderManager class
>   : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree required-type       :
>   org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree converter-type      :
>   org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter path
>   : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/HeaderManager line number
>   : 14
>   -------------------------------   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:77)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readBareItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:132)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.unmarshal(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:94)
>     ... 12 more Caused by:
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException:
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HeaderManager     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:81)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService$XStreamWrapper$1.realClass(SaveService.java:98)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readBareItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:131)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
>     ... 23 more

**pom.xml file**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.11.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jmeter</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <overrideRootLogLevel>debug</overrideRootLogLevel>
            <propertiesUser>
                <jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format>xml</jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format>
            </propertiesUser>
            <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
            <ignoreResultFailures>true</ignoreResultFailures>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

<!-- <plugin>
    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>analyze</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>verify</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        source file that contains jmeter result data. Needs to be XML format 
            or a GZIPed XML format
        <source>D:\Ecllipse_project_workspace2\slt_automation\target\jmeter\results\*</source>

        directory where to store analysis report files. At least a file "summary.txt" 
            will be stored here.
        <targetDirectory>D:\Ecllipse_project_workspace2\slt_automation\target\jmeter\reports</targetDirectory>
        <logsDirectory>D:\Ecllipse_project_workspace2\slt_automation\target\jmeter\logs</logsDirectory>

        <processAllFilesFound>true</processAllFilesFound>
    </configuration>
</plugin> -->



<plugin>
    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>analyze</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>verify</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <!-- source file that contains jmeter result data. Needs to be XML format 
            or a GZIPed XML format -->
        <source>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/*</source>

        <!-- directory where to store analysis report files. At least a file "summary.txt" 
            will be stored here. -->
        <targetDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/reports</targetDirectory>
        <processAllFilesFound>true</processAllFilesFound>
    </configuration>
</plugin>


<plugin>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-graph-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <inputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/slt_autoMa_Test.csv</inputFile>
        <graphs>
            <graph>
                <pluginType>ResponseTimesOverTime</pluginType>
                <width>800</width>
                <height>600</height>
                <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/slt_autoMa_Test.png</outputFile>
            </graph>
        </graphs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 3):

From the error you're getting it seems that your test is using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) and you don't have the [`ApacheJMeter_http`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_http/) package which provides this class.

The interim solution would be adding the next [Maven dependency](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) to your *pom.xml*:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_http -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_http</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I would also recommend removing these `httpcore` and `xstream` dependencies from your *pom.xml* as Maven will get them as [transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) of JMeter Core and HTTP packages.

---

Depending on your test nature you might need other packages, [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/), so it's quite hard to say what else you may need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It has removed some errors and given me some response from JMeter but I am so perplexed right now after seeing the logs given by Jmeter. I am going to post that errors as a seprate answer within this page and you can check the same from that result, Please assist me and have a look on these errors, Thank You !!